# Is there a generalisation of the ordinary cross product ${\vec A}\times {\vec B}$ in quantum mechanics?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

The inner product $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ of two state vectors in the Hilbert space can be thought of as the generalization of the ordinary dot product $\vec{A}\cdot{\vec B}$ of two vectors in 3D space. This is an appropriate generalization in the sense that for ${\vec A}=\vec{B}$, the dot product gives the norm square of ${\vec A}$ and similarly for $\phi=\psi$ we get norm square of $\phi$.

Does the ordinary cross-product ${\vec A}\times {\vec B}$ of two vectors in 3D have any generalization in quantum mechanics? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/752774/811225) , [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/424482/811225), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2555693/811225)

Comment: The answer is obviously "no!!",  but how do you prove it? The cross product is problematic to generalize usefully for anything but 2-vectors, as you see in the linked questions, and the generalizations become pointless for the infinite-dimensional vectors of QM. What's your point?