# Why can't two planes be orthogonal in $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I think my confusion comes from not knowing the difference between *orthogonal* and *orthogonal subspaces*.

So according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52822), two planes can't be "orthogonal" in $R^3$. How does having more than three dimensions resolve this?

I think the argument is two planes can't be orthogonal subspaces to each other because their intersection is a line, so if we take any two vectors on that line dot them together, we won't have a zero dot product.

However, two planes can be geometrically orthogonal to each other right? For example, the xy and xz planes are perpendicular, so they must be orthogonal to each other right?

Can someone explain why having more than three dimensions means we can have orthogonal plane subspaces? Don't we still have the same problem as before?

Comment: The planes $$\{(x,y,0,0):x,y\in\mathbb R\}$$ and $$\{(0,0,x,y):x,y\in\mathbb R\}$$ are orthogonal in $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: The two planes $x=w=0$ and $z=w=0$ would still exhibit the phenomenon you describe, but two generally-positioned planes in $R^4$ meet in a point, so we can find orthogonal planes, as in @Ruy's comment.

Comment: I remember learning in school that two planes were orthogonal if their normal vectors had dot product equal to zero. Is this not true?

Comment: Yes, when you're talking about two planes in $\Bbb R^3$, the planes are orthogonal iff their normal vectors are orthogonal. However, this is just a different concept from the linear algebra concept of orthogonal subspaces (which needn't be orthogonal complements, by the way).

Comment: Just to be clear - 
$$$$
Orthogonal if and only if perpendicular
$$$$
Orthogonal Subspace if every pair of vectors (one from each space) has inner product zero?

Comment: Yes, BigBear, that's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of orthogonal planes, the requirement is that each plane
has a basis of two orthogonal vectors and that one of the vectors
of each pair is shared between the two planes and the other vector
of each pair form a pair orthogonal to each other. Here we have
three mutually orthogonal vectors in three dimensional space.

In the case of orthogonal planes as subspaces, we require that each
vector of each pair is orthogonal to *each* vector of the other pair.
This requires the dimension of the ambient space to be at least $\,2+2=4.$