# Is a hyper-plane uniquely defined by a single normal vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, machine-learning, orthogonality

So I was always taught that planes have two directions that are normal, or perpendicular, to it. However, upon reading this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/52864/582205), in dimensions higher than $R^3$ there can be more than one vector normal to a hyperplane.

This got me thinking, suppose our plane is $$ w + x + y + 0z = w + x + y = 0$$
Then our normal vector is $[1,1,1, 0]$. All vectors on the plane are normal to that vector. However, the same is true for $[1,1,1, 999]$ which points in a different direction, right(please tell me if this is actually pointing in the same direction and I'm an idiot)?

So essentially, we can't uniquely define a plane by a single vector(or negative one times that vector)? There are multiple vectors that can be orthogonal that plane, is this correct.

How come then in machine learning, our perceptron algorithm only uses a single theta(normal vector) to define the plane? Couldn't it be the case that a different normal vector could produce a different classification answer?

Comment: A plane in three space has a single normal direction, planes in $\mathbb R^n$ have $n-2$ normal directions.

Comment: It is not true that all points in the plane are orthogonal to $[1,1,1,999]$. For example, $[0,0,0,1]$ is a point in the plane.

Comment: @lulu "Hyperplanes" typically refer to $(n-1)$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann  Sure...but the OP appears to use "plane" and "hyperplane" interchangeably,   which is not standard.

Comment: @BigBear Note that the answer you've linked uses "plane" to refer to 2-dimensional subspaces, which is distinct from the meaning of "hyperplane".

Comment: If $\mathbf{n}$ is normal to the plane, so is $c\mathbf{n}$ for any $c \neq 0$.

Comment: Also, the normal vector alone does not define the plane:  you must also know a point on it.

Comment: @lulu, Ben Grossmann, Randall Woah.... this so helpful!

Comment: Just to solidify with an example, if our plane is $$\{(x,y, 0, 0,0)| x,y \text{ are real numbers}\}$$ then our normals can be $[1,1, 0,0,0]$ or $[1,1, 0,0,9]$ or $[1,1, 0,9,9]$ or anything following this pattern?

Also, I don't know if I'm just being extremely blind but is there an easy way to describe this plane $$\{(x,y, 0, 0,0)| x,y \text{ are real numbers}\}$$ with an equation?

Comment: @lulu if there are $n-2$ normal directions in n-dimensional space, then does that mean there are more $n-2$ vectors that are normal to it? My reasoning is we can take a linear combination of any of those $n-2$ vectors and we'll have produce a vector that points in a different direction.

Comment: As was pointed out earlier, it's not clear whether you are referring to a "plane" (i.e. a two dimensional subspace) or to a "hyperplane" (i.e. a codimension $1$ subspace).

Comment: @lulu Ah, yes. So in the comments I mean - does a $2$ dimensional plane have more than $n-2$ normal vectors in $n$-dimensional space? I'm guessing if we can have $n-2$ normal vectors to the $2$-dimensional plane, then a linear combination of the vectors is also going to be normal to the $2$-dimensional plane. As a result, we'll have more than $n-2$ normal vectors to a $2$-dimensional plane. Is this correct?

Comment: And how are you counting vectors?  Even for a plane in $\mathbb R^3$...There are infinitely many if you allow scalar multiples to be treated as different vectors.  If you normalize to require unit length then there are $2$.  If you regard all parallel vectors as specifying the same "direction", then there is only one.

Comment: @lulu Hi, sorry for the long delay. I mean if we normalize to require unit length. From what I'm thinking - 
$$$$
If a $2$-dimensional plane is in a $n$-dimensional space, there are $n-2$ linearly independent vectors that are normal to that plane. However, if there are more than $n-2$ directions that are parallel to that plane since taking a linear combination of the $n-2$ vector normals produces a different direction. Is there an exact number of directions perpendicular to the plane in $n$ dimensions? I'm thinking there's an infinite number of directions that are perpendicular to it, so no?

Comment: Maybe it would be insightful to consider the span of a single vector in $R^3$, for example, the z-axis. The set of vectors orthogonal to that defines the $xy$-plane. There is a natural sense in which one could say there are an infinite number of normal directions, but there is only one normal plane.

It is similar in your case. Choose any $n-2$ linearly independent vectors normal to the plane; those are your basis vectors. They aren't unique but the hyperplane they define is. (I'm assuming through the origin, not worrying about affine stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need another scalar to determine the "location" of the hyperplane – the (signed) distance from origin.  However, if you limit to only hyperplanes through origin, then that scalar is always 0, and the (normalized) hyperplane normal vector uniquely (except for sign) determines such planes.

Also, ignoring a nonzero real scale factor $\lambda$ ($0 \ne \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$), there is exactly one vector $\mathbf{n}$ normal (perpendicular) to a hyperplane.

That is, if $\mathbf{n}$ is normal to the hyperplane, then all $\lambda \mathbf{n}$ are also normal to the hyperplane.  Conversely, if both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are normal to a hyperplane, then $\mathbf{a} = \lambda \mathbf{b}$.  Do note that $\lambda$ can be positive or negative.

You can also define a hyperplane parametrically using $N-1$ linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{b}_k$ ($k = 1, 2, \dots, N-1$) and optionally a local origin $\mathbf{o}$, as
$$\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{o} + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} y_k \mathbf{b}_k$$
where $y_k$ are the $N-1$ local coordinates on the hyperplane.  But in this case, all $\mathbf{b}_k$ are perpendicular/normal to the hyperplane normal vector, i.e.
$$\mathbf{b}_k \cdot \mathbf{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} b_{k,i} n_i = 0 ~ \text{for} ~ k = 1, 2, \dots, N-1$$

If those vectors $\mathbf{b}_k$ are nonzero, and they are all perpendicular to each other ($\mathbf{b}_k \cdot \mathbf{b}_j$ is nonzero only when $k = j$), then they form a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) for the hyperplane.

---

Let us define a [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) as an $N-1$-dimensional object in $N$-dimensional space, that divides that space into two separate subspaces.  (This applies to affine hyperplanes and to vector hyperplanes, but not to projective hyperplanes.)

(In 1D, a hyperplane is a point, splitting the one-dimensional space into two parts.  In 2D, a hyperplane is a line, infinitely long.  In 3D, a hyperplane is a plane.  And so on.)

The implicit equation for a hyperplane in $N$ dimensions in Cartesian coordinates is
$$\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i x_i = d \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\mathbf{n} = (n_1, n_2, \dots, n_N)$ is the hyperplane normal coordinates, $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N)$ is the coordinates for any point on the plane, and $d$ is the signed distance of the hyperplane from origin in units of the hyperplane normal length.

When (and only when) $d = 0$, does the hyperplane pass through origin.

Note that $\mathbf{n}$ must be a nonzero vector, $\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2 \gt 0$.  (In $\eqref{1}$, if $\mathbf{n}$ is a zero vector, the equation is either nowhere true (when $d \ne 0$) or everywhere true (when $d = 0$), i.e. either refers to the entire space or a nothing.  Neither is a valid hyperplane.)

We can label the subspaces the hyperplane divides space into, via
$$\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i x_i = \begin{cases}
\gt d, \text{"Positive" subspace} \\
= d, \text{On the hyperplane} \\
\lt d, \text{"Negative" subspace} \\
\end{cases} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where *"Positive"* and *"Negative"* are not standard labels, just names I picked for illustration.  In fact, in different contexts even concepts like *"inside"* can be either one ($\gt d$ or $\lt d$; or, including the hyperplane, $\ge d$ or $\le d$), so it is important to describe how one chooses to label the two subspaces.  Note that the hyperplane itself has zero "thickness", so it is not a subspace: its hypervolume is zero.  (It is usually included in one of the subspaces.)

When hyperplanes are used as in $\eqref{2}$, they are called *half-spaces*.  (A *closed half-space*, if it includes the hyperplane; an *open half-space*, if it excludes the hyperplane.)  Convex [polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope) with $K$ faces (noting that $K \gt N$) are defined by $K$ half-spaces corresponding to its faces.

Note how the hyperplane normal $\mathbf{n}$ alone does not uniquely define it; we also need the scalar, the signed distance from origin.

Because we can multiply both sides of $\eqref{1}$ by any nonzero real without affecting the hyperplane, the tuple
$$\left(\frac{\mathbf{n}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}} ; \frac{d}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}} \right) = \left( \frac{n_1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}}, \frac{n_2}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}}, \dots, \frac{n_N}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}} ; \frac{d}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}} \right) \tag{4}\label{4}$$
uniquely defines a half-space.  Scaling the equation by the Euclidean length of the hyperplane normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ effectively eliminates the magnitude of any scale factor out.

Negating both $\mathbf{n}$ (negating each normal vector component $n_i$) and $d$ divides the space into the same two subspaces, but selects the other half-space.

That is, we can negate $d$ and all $n_i$ in $\eqref{1}$ without changing the definition of the hyperplane.  Therefore $\eqref{4}$ uniquely defines each hyperplane only if we consider tuples $\left(\frac{n_1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}}, \frac{n_2}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}}, \dots, \frac{n_N}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}} ; \frac{d}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{-n_1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}}, \frac{-n_2}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}}, \dots, \frac{-n_N}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}} ; \frac{-d}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}}\right)$ the same.

Alternatively but equivalently, you can say that after scaling $\mathbf{n}$ and $d$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} n_i^2}}$, i.e. having *unit* normal vector $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ ($\left\lVert\hat{\mathbf{n}}\right\rVert = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \hat{n}_i^2} = 1$) and signed distance from origin $d$ for the hyperplane, tuples $\left(\hat{\mathbf{n}}; d\right)$ uniquely define the hyperplane, if you consider $\left(\hat{\mathbf{n}}; d\right)$ and $\left(-\hat{\mathbf{n}}; -d\right)$ the same.

Specifying unit normal vectors is useful in other ways as well.  Not only is $d$ directly the signed distance from origin (instead of in units of normal length), but if $\hat{\mathbf{a}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{b}}$ are two unit normals, the dihedral angle $\varphi$ between them fulfills $\cos\varphi = \hat{\mathbf{a}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{b}} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i b_i$.

Answer (score 3):

The essential idea to understand is that of the hodge dual. It goes as follows: In a d dimensional space, there is a natural association between n dimensional object and n-d dimensional object. So, suppose we are working in 3D, there is a natural association between 1 dimensional object and 2 dimensional object. Here are list of all the correspondance in 3D space:

Scalars <--> Volumes

Vectors <--> Areas

We can also see in 2 dimensional space, we have a correspondance:

Scalars <--> Areas

Vectors <--> Vectors

Let me be more specific about association point. If we are to build up the higher dimensional object from a set of basis object , then the size of that basis for the n dim and n-d dim would be same.

Of course, the above idea only defines upto parallel shift. To get a specific hyper plane/ plane, you need to also specify the point on this object.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: And yes, you can treat area/ volume as a vector space itself. Search up [Geometric Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60z_hpEAtD8)

Comment: Sorry, I know you said there was a "natural association"... what is this association? I'm having a hard time understanding the natural association between 'scalars and volumes' or between 'vectors and areas'

Comment: Well in 3d volume is just a number but if you were 4d the volume would have 4 components. For vector and area you can see that in 3d there are three perpendicular plane for three perpendicular direction. Z goes to xy , y go to xz, x go to zy etc @BigBear

Comment: Welp I tried my best :(

Answer (score 0):

Just believe in simple abstraction of a hyperplane defined as follows:

A hyperplane is a set of the form
$H=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n |a^\top x=b, a\in \mathbb{R}^n, b\in \mathbb{R}\}.$ Here, $a$ is called a normal vector to the hyperplane H with a unique direction $\hat{a}$.

Further, an Euclidean space being a Hilbert space, the normal vector $a$ introduce a representation of a linear function with respect to the dot product as an inner product in the space. So, as per Riesz representation theorem, we may call the normal vector $a$ a dual to the vector $x$.